# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when creating cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to reuse cell created in my storyboard,

I'm using this code:

```
MyTableView * mytableview;

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
mytableview = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTable"];


AlertCell *cell;

cell = [mytableview.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"alertCell"];
cell.message.text = @"some text";

return cell;
```

I get this error:

```
[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe02b7d0
```

this line eventually generates the error:

```
[mytableview.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"alertCell"];
```

- The table view when using the cell is programaticlly created.
- Everything i wanted works! but i got the errors in the log anyway

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure the error you are seeing is in this code. `objectForKeyedSubscript` is a method on `NSDictionary` commonly used for subscripted referencing (i.e. myDict[@"key"]). `NSArray` has a similar method `objectAtIndexedSubscript` (myArray[3]). Are you sure that this error isn't caused by, perhaps, assigning an array to something that expects a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create the table view when the cell is created.

You have to create the table view in a method that i called when the view controller is created, such as `viewDidLoad`.

Then in the cell method use the `tableView` pointer that is included in the method.

Also, the error actually indicates a problem with your datasource as well.

There are so many apparent knowledge gaps, maybe the best way is to read through the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1).

Comment: You *can* create *a* table when the cell is created, but you *should not*. It looks to me that the OP is loading some other view controller with some other table just to create a new cell, which seems very inefficient at best.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand when you are creating table. You should not instantiate at the same time. Why you needed to call this line?

```
mytableview = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTable"];
```

If you want to use tableview, just create it normally and add it to your viewcontroller instead of using above line of code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.rowHeight = 45;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
```

Implement tableview's data source and delegate methods. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newFriendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newFriendCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
//do your stuff
return cell;
}
```